# How get all values from custom label in apex code

Tags: apex, metadata-api

I've a custom label with default value in italian and two translations. Can I get all values (Italian and translated value) in apex code via metadata?
For example:

```
public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService(){

    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
    return service;
}

MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();

MetadataService.CustomLabel customLabel =  (MetadataService.CustomLabel) service.readMetadata('CustomLabel', new String[] { 'CustomLabelName' }).getRecords()[0];
System.debug(customLabel.value); //print the default value
```

Comment: These links should give you an idea on how to proceed:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_translations.htm & https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customlabels.htm